# How to update the width/height of a Pixi Container/Sprite/Graphic that initially has a value of 0

Tags: pixi.js

The PixiJS documentation says about a `Container`'s width (and height), which `Sprite`s and `Graphics` also inherit:

> The width of the Container, setting this will actually modify the scale to achieve the value set

I have some objects that are initially set to a height and width of 0 and also initialize a Sprite/Graphic representation of themselves at that time, to be updated in position/dimensions at some later point. This seems like a fairly simple idea, but because setting the width/height is actually a scale and not a direct assignment, I can't modify the width/height if it's been initialized to zero.

Is there some alternative way to set the dimensions or is a Pixi object initialized with a height/width of 0 really stuck that way forever?

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that there is no way to change a container's size because it was already drawn on the canvas as a static shape. You can transform it (scaling, skewing, etc.) and redraw it, but you just can't directly change it.

Comment: Unfortunate if this is true, I guess I just hoped Pixi.js would abstract this away in some way, even if it required recreating the shape.